# How to: Automatically edit my input and extract only certain info into new input

Tags: r, loops

Noob here, I hope I can make it clear what I need.

I have a survey that we want to present. It has got about 200 columns. For each column, there are these lines in the data cleaning script, exported from the survey platform. It looks like this

```
# Survey type: A
data[, 72] <- as.character(data[, 72])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[72] <- "Joint grant proposals submitted"
names(data)[72] <- "E31_SQ005"

# Survey type: F
data[, 74] <- as.numeric(data[, 74])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[74] <- "Have you submitted other joint grant proposals?"
data[, 74] <- factor(data[, 74], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("yes", "no"))
names(data)[74] <- "E311"`
# Survey Field type: A
data[, 17] <- as.character(data[, 17])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[17] <- "[Other] I came to know about the VSP through the following sources:"
names(data)[17] <- "B1_other"
# Survey type: F
data[, 18] <- as.numeric(data[, 18])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[18] <- "I used the following sources to inform myself about the VSP:"
data[, 18] <- factor(data[, 18], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Yes", "Not selected"))
names(data)[18] <- "B2_SQ002"
```

So there are some iterations with 4 lines of code and some with 5. I need to extract the info after the <- in the attributes(data)....-line and the code in the last line. Then, they need to be put into a print-command and the end code needs to be in a table(df$code) command as well.
Finally I wish my script to look like 200 iterations with different info of this structure:
print("Code:Code from last line")
print("attributes phrase")
table(df$Code from last line)

I was suggested using loops but researching that hasnt helped yet. I'd appreciate any help on how to achieve what I need, I hope I made myself understood. Any tips on what to learn, any (semi-)ready code or anything else would be great! Thanks alot!

I've tried asking Chatgpt but that only yielded a RegEx construction that did not fulfill what I need.
I thought to maybe just edit the script using the replace function in crtl+f, but each line has another number from 3 to 207, so I cant just use that feature either to edit my input script

Comment: Hi Pietro! It's kinda hard to know what you want without a larger example. It seems like your code could probably be condensed significantly, but it's hard to say without seeing more

Comment: Hi, thanks, here are some more lines, it just repeats like that:
Oops., I can only put in 500 characters....

Comment: Hi, thanks, here are some more lines, it just repeats like that:
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 13] <- as.numeric(data[, 13])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[13] <- "question 1:"
data[, 13] <- factor(data[, 13], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Yes", "Not selected"))
names(data)[13] <- "B1_SQ002"
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 14] <- as.numeric(data[, 14])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[14] <- " question 15:"
data[, 14] <- factor(data[, 14], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Yes", "Not selected"))
names(data)[14] <- "B1_SQ003"

they all look like that b1 all the way to k4_SQ004

Comment: Pietro edit your question to add them in please

Comment: okay, so, do you have a vector (or vector) of types you want each of the  columns to be? If the data is imported from somewhere else, e.g. using read_csv(), then you can specify the types while importing

Comment: in general, I would say put all of the data you're wanting to use in lists or data.frames or vectors, and use them that way, across many columns, instead of doing things column by column.

Comment: yes, the first line is 
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/.....)
I dont have the vecotrs yet, the script that the survey program let me download looks like the small excerpt in my original comment - just 200x that :D 
thanks for your help, sorry if I'm not making myself perfetly clear

Comment: thank you for that! It's hard to give you an answer without some sample question we can work with... 200 columns is a lot though! Have you considered using `read_csv()` instead?

Comment: basically, your question is about your code being badly structured, but you've only shown us 3/200ths of your code. Ideally, you want everything to be in vectors (e.g. instead of `names(data)[1] <- "blah"`, `names(data)[2] <- 'hello'` etc. you have one vector of `new_names` and you do `names(data) <- new_names`

Comment: I can see why ChatGPT gave you a regex solution, because if your code is as long as it sounds, it sounds like you need a regex solution. But without seeing all of your code, it would be difficult to know for certain what would work - if the code was turned into a vector of strings, then you could use something like `str_extract(s, "names(data)")` on it to get the new column names, but it could match many things

Comment: Okay thank you. The code literally is about 200 blocks of the 5 line code there, the only thing that changes is the question prompt, the code at the ende and the numbers in the rectagular brackets. The latter go up by one, with each new block of code, the question is different everytime obvioulsy and the code too. Those range from A1_SQ001 to L4_SQ006.

Comment: It's not even that the code is badly structured, I just need a different code that I dont feel like typing manually and I hope I could rework some of the existing code into a new script, this time not used to clean data but to present it. 
Again, excuse my inexperience and maybe dumb comments :D

Comment: @PietroPisellone, are you looking for a table like this? 
`data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE, col = c(72L, 74L, 17L, 18L, 13L, 14L), info = c("Joint grant proposals submitted","Have you submitted other joint grant proposals?", "[Other] I came to know about the VSP through the following sources:", "I used the following sources to inform myself about the VSP:","question 1:"," question 15:"), code = c("E31_SQ005","E311","B1_other", "B2_SQ002","B1_SQ002","B1_SQ003"))`

Comment: with respect Pietro if your code is 1000 lines long with almost every line being repeated 5 times, it's badly structured and desperately needs refactoring

Comment: @Mark This is a script automatically created by LimeSurvey to read and label the data  of survey results for further analysis.

Comment: no offense taken, the data cleaning code is exported from lime survey, its their code that would be bad - not mine - completely disregarding I couldnt have done it myself :D

Comment: @adriano This is really cool, but not exactely what I need! Thanks a lot for helping out.
 What I really want is just a convenient and not manual way to get an edited input script. I can extract info from data frames and all, but I have the necessary detail and info in my script, not in a data frame. Like imagine you had to compile data into one list from the word docs and the clickage that involves. I wanna avoid that, but how do I conveniently avoid that using "only" my input script?

Comment: So I watched some vids on loops and had a noob spark. The question promt I wanna read in the output is saved in a vector of sort like this:
attributes(data)$variable.labels[7] <- "PROMT"
the number in [ ] goes from 1 to 179.
What I thought is: could I use a loop to make it do something like this:
for (i in {
attributes(data)$variable.labels[1:179]
print(names(data)[1:179])
table(DF$names(data)[1:179]
print(i) 
}
I know this doesnt work, since it would need another way of counting up, but I dont know how to. Would you have any ideas?

Comment: Okay guys, so with your help and a little aide from my friend Chadgpt I figured out the following: 
# Loop over the indices
for (i in indices) {

  variable_label <- ifelse(!is.null(attributes(dataONA)$variable.labels), attributes(dataONA)$variable.labels[i], "")

  variable_name <- names(dataONA)[i]
  # Print the customized output
  cat("Index", i, variable_label, variable_name, "\n")
  
  if (exists("dataONA")) {
    print(table(dataONA[, variable_name]))
  }
}
The only issue is that it either prints literally "variable_label" or nothing in its stead. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @PietroPisellone I understood you need the script. The table above was intended to validate the expected output!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to at least get you close to your desired result. Basically this requires to read the script line by line and putting the content in a data frame which could then be further processed to retrieve the desired information. As a result you will get a dataframe containing the variable or question codes and the labels:

```r
text <-
  '
# Survey type: A
data[, 72] <- as.character(data[, 72])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[72] <- "Joint grant proposals submitted"
names(data)[72] <- "E31_SQ005"

# Survey type: F
data[, 74] <- as.numeric(data[, 74])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[74] <- "Have you submitted other joint grant proposals?"
data[, 74] <- factor(data[, 74], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("yes", "no"))
names(data)[74] <- "E311"
# Survey Field type: A
data[, 17] <- as.character(data[, 17])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[17] <- "[Other] I came to know about the VSP through the following sources:"
names(data)[17] <- "B1_other"
# Survey type: F
data[, 18] <- as.numeric(data[, 18])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[18] <- "I used the following sources to inform myself about the VSP:"
data[, 18] <- factor(data[, 18], levels=c(1,0),labels=c("Yes", "Not selected"))
names(data)[18] <- "B2_SQ002"
'

# Filename
file <- tempfile(".R")

### Just for the reprex: Create an example file
writeLines(text, file)
###

# Read the script
x <- data.frame(value = trimws(readLines(file)))

x$rowid <- cumsum(grepl("^#", x$value))
x <- x[x$rowid > 0, ]
x <- x[!x$value == "", ]

x$stat <- "drop"
x$stat[grepl("^names\\(", x$value)] <- "code"
x$stat[grepl("variable\\.labels", x$value)] <- "label"
x <- x[!x$stat == "drop", ]

x <- reshape(x, idvar = "rowid", timevar = "stat", direction = "wide")
names(x) <- gsub("^value\\.", "", names(x))

x$code <- gsub("^.*?<-\\s?(.*)$", "\\1", x$code)
x$label <- gsub("^.*?<-\\s?(.*)$", "\\1", x$label)

x[] <- lapply(x, \(x) {
  trimws(gsub("\"", "", x, fixed = TRUE))
})

x <- x[c("code", "label")]

x
#>         code
#> 4  E31_SQ005
#> 9       E311
#> 14  B1_other
#> 18  B2_SQ002
#>                                                                  label
#> 4                                      Joint grant proposals submitted
#> 9                      Have you submitted other joint grant proposals?
#> 14 [Other] I came to know about the VSP through the following sources:
#> 18        I used the following sources to inform myself about the VSP:
```